# i want a dotted circle in canvas ctx.fillText(".",500,400)

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

i want to make a dotted circle

```
var c = document.getElementById("layerCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.font = "15px Arial";
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";

        ctx.fillText(".",500,400);
```

how do i use the ctx.arc to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can draw a dot at any point on a circle's circumference using `context.arc` and some trigonometry.**

You can calculate a point at any angle on the circle's circumference using:

```
var x=centerX+radius*Math.cos(desiredRadianAngleOnCircle);
var y=centerY+radius*Math.sin(desiredRadianAngleOnCircle);
```

If you want to draw dots at interval [x,y]'s along the circle's circumference, you can calculate a set of `desiredRadianAngleOnCircle`'s like this:

```
// calc the interval to draw 60 dots around the circle
var interval=(Math.PI*2)/60;   

// increament desiredRadianAngleOnCircle for each new x,y
desiredRadianAngleOnCircle += interval;
```

And you can draw a dot using a filled context.arc:

```
 context.beginPath();
 context.arc(x,y,3,0,Math.PI*2);
 context.closePath();
 context.fill();
```

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var context=canvas.getContext("2d");

var dotsPerCircle=60;

var interval=(Math.PI*2)/dotsPerCircle;   

var centerX=150;
var centerY=150;
var radius=100;

for(var i=0;i<dotsPerCircle;i++){

    desiredRadianAngleOnCircle = interval*i;
    
    var x = centerX+radius*Math.cos(desiredRadianAngleOnCircle);
    var y = centerY+radius*Math.sin(desiredRadianAngleOnCircle);

     context.beginPath();
     context.arc(x,y,3,0,Math.PI*2);
     context.closePath();
     context.fill();
    
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: somehow it does not work for me can you show me the total code of the circle you drew ?

Comment: or have a look at milton-chocolate.nl to see what i m trying to do in canvas

Comment: @spalburg. That bit of javascript starting with `var canvas...` is pretty much the whole code. I have a canvas element in the body, but that's about it.